# Declaration of DataSet and DataRow being skipped

Tags: c#, debugging

I seem to have a problem with my code. Below I have a method of a class where I create a custom class object, set its connectionString and call it's method '.Sql', where I place an SQL command; it retrieves values from my database and stores it in my declared Dataset. However, the execution of a DataSet (and dRow) is being skipped; any ideas why?

```
public static void setRGBOColour()
{
    DatabaseConnection objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
    DataSet ds;
    DataRow dRow; 

    objConnect.Connection_String = absDefault.conString;
    // Finds the user's current theme colour and changes
    objConnect.SQL = String.Format(
        "SELECT * FROM tblColourTheme WHERE [StudentID]={0}", absDefault._idNumber);
    ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

    dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]; 
    _red = Convert.ToInt16(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2));
    _green = Convert.ToInt16(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3));
    _blue = Convert.ToInt16(dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4));
}
```

If you want to see my DatabaseConnection class, [I have included the code in here](http://pastebin.com/Zu4f0dWx).

[Here is a GIF if what I am getting after debugging](https://gyazo.com/2fbe1567f7583bc77bda134b8e2d2a7b).

If you could help me figure out the problem that I am unaware of or am not doing, please tell me.

Comment: put Try/Catch around you code and read the exception message. Is `GetConnection` a method? Because if it is you need to call it with parens `()`

Comment: Just did; my gawd. I've solved the problem.